# How can I change my Battle.net account email if I forgot my secret answer?

Tags: account-management

I usually enter random data in the secret question field for security purposes (i.e. I only want one way for someone to access my account, via the password. No need for a back-door security answer). Since I always document my username and passwords, I have never needed to use the security answer. However, this is the first time that I have seen that a site requires the secret answer in order to do something on your account.

When I go to modify my email address, in addition to my password, it asks for my secret answer. Is there any way to modify my email address without providing this secret answer?

Comment: Should probably be in the games stack exchange. Vote to close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Seems like](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=20860798051&sid=3000) the only option is to [call](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/about/contact.html) the billing department.